# How to see HQL final query

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpql

I'm trying to run the following query and getting a null pointer exception.  I've verified that `WHERE lockedTimestamp <= (GETDATE() - CAST('00:06' AS datetime)` is valid msSQL because I can run it manually and it'll work fine.  It appears HQL (Hibernate Query Language) may not like it.  Any thoughts on how I can go about debugging this?

```
Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Content c WHERE lockedTimestamp <= (GETDATE() - CAST('00:06' AS datetime))");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a much more obvious and intuitive calculation, e.g.

```
SELECT c FROM Content c WHERE lockedTimestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -6, GETDATE());
```

? I gather this isn't valid in JPQL either, but more for the general query itself in case other users stumble across this question...

As an aside, why not put this query in a stored procedure? Surely hibernate can call a stored procedure, then it doesn't need to try to interpret or reverse engineer your query.

Comment: +1 for the easier to ready query.... how would I use that with createQuery() though ^_^

Comment: @Webnet don't know, sorry - I know SQL but I don't use hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

`EntityManager.createQuery` expects a query string in [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html) (not HQL, and not SQL). JPQL does not define a `CAST` function.

I'd compute the timestamp limit in Java, and pass it as parameter to the query:

```
Date limit = ...;
this.em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Content c WHERE lockedTimestamp <= ?")
       .setParameter(0, limit);
```

Answer (score 1):

To **debug** sql, you can show the queries that launches Hibernate by adding the configuration **hibernate.show_sql=true** in the hibernate configuration properties.

The queries will be shown in console, and it's the exact query that hibernate make to the database.